# Internal $2$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, internal-categories, internalization

> Has the notion of an internal $2$-category been studied, or more generally an internal $n$-category? Do we have any examples of naturally occurring internal $2$-categories/$n$-categories?

The motivation here is understanding internalization at higher levels.

In particular, it seems the 'nuts and bolts' set theoretical definitions of higher $n$-categories as a class of objects, a class of $1$-cells, a class of $2$-cells, ..., a class of $n$-cells, together with functions between them for domains, codomains, and identities, and functions out of pullbacks for compositions (see below for an example), is more naturally internalized at higher levels than the 'high-tech' definitions relying on component $n-1$ categories for each pair of objects together with $n-1$ functors for composition, $n-1$ natural transformations for associative coherence, $n-1$ modifications for coherence of associative coherence, $\dots$.

This seems counterintuitive (even ironic) in light of the goal of internal category theory -- internalization is supposed to allow us to eschew any use of sets in our categorical reasoning, but we have to use a very set theoretical definition of higher categories in order to correctly internalize them? Perhaps I'm just not seeing a simple internalization of the latter definition.

To make the question more precise, here's one possible internalization of the 'nuts and bolts' definition of a [bicategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bicategory) on the nlab:

---

Let $\mathfrak{C}$ be a $2$-category with $1$-cell pullbacks. An *internal $2$-category* $\mathrm{C}$ in $\mathfrak{C}$ consists of

1. An object of objects ${\bf Ob}_\mathrm{C}\in{\bf Ob}_\mathfrak{C}$.
2. An object of $1$-cells ${\bf 1-Hom}_\mathrm{C}\in{\bf Ob}_\mathfrak{C}$.
3. An object of $2$-cells ${\bf 2-Hom}_\mathrm{C}\in{\bf Ob}_\mathfrak{C}$.
4. $1$-cells as below for domains, codomains and identities: [image]
5. $1$-cells as below for vertical and horizontal composition: [image] where we pull back ${\bf 2-Hom}_\mathrm{C}$ over ${\bf 1-Hom}_\mathrm{C}$ using ${\sf dom}$ and ${\sf cod}$ for vertical composition, and over ${\bf Ob}_\mathrm{C}$ using ${\sf dom\circ dom}$ and ${\sf cod\circ cod}$ for horizontal composition.
6. A $2$-cell $\gamma$ as below for associative coherence of composition:[image]
7. $2$-cells $\iota_\ell$ and $\iota_r$ as below for left and right unital coherence: [image] [image]

With all the above data satisfying appropriate coherence diagrams (in the spirit of bicategories), this definition seems to shake out correctly -- realized in the discrete $2$-category ${\bf Set}$ this yields a strict $2$-category, since all $2$-cells will be identities. Realizing it in the $2$-category of categories yields something else, a 'triple category' of sorts, but perhaps this discrepancy has to do with the fact that we've internalized a set-theoretical definition of $2$-categories rather than a $1$-categorical definition.

Has this idea been explored, or is it trivialized by some higher notion of internal categories already in the literature?

Comment: It seems odd to ask for an isomorphism $(fg)h\cong f(gh)$ in $\mathfrak C$. Better to ask for them to be isomorphic in $C$, so that the map $\left(\circ_C\circ (\circ_C\times 1),\circ_C\circ (1\times \circ_C)\right)$, with codomain $\mathbf{1-Hom}_C\times \mathbf{1-Hom}_C$, is supposed to factor through $(\mathbf{dom},\mathbf{cod}):\mathbf{2-Hom}_C\to \mathbf{1-Hom}_C\times \mathbf{1-Hom}_C$, giving the associator, etc. The theory of bicategories is essentially algebraic and can be modeled in any cat with finite limits.

Comment: For a semilocally 2-connected space $X$, the fundamental bigroupoid $\Pi_2(X)$ [lifts to be internal to $\mathbf{Top}$](https://doi.org/10.1007/s40062-016-0160-0).

Comment: Dominique Bourn has written a few papers on (strict) $n$-groupoids internal to a category with finite limits (or sometimes an exact category). You can find some titles and short summaries on [his webpage](http://www-lmpa.univ-littoral.fr/~bourn/).

Comment: @KevinCarlson Both choices are sensible, though in general distinct.  One might say that one gives an "internal 2-category" and the other an "internal bicategory", with the warning that an internal 2-category is not "fully strict" when internalized in a 2-category rather than a 1-category.

Comment: You might be interested in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28n+%C3%97+k%29-category and the references at the bottom.

Comment: @MikeShulman Ah, so the isomorphism in $\mathfrak C$ is a reason why $(fg)h$ and $f(gh)$ are "equal", as opposed to an isomorphism in $C$ between two things that might have been more strictly equal, interesting.

Comment: @KevinCarlson It was clever not to write down the domain of that map ;). The pointer is appreciated -- regarding the last sentence, you're saying we can interpret any statement about bicategories inside a category with finite limits, so we don't 'gain anything' by internalizing them in a higher setting? Nick Gurski gave a fully algebraic formalism for weak $3$-categories in his 2009 thesis (and proved a corresponding coherence theorem for weak $3$-functors), so presumably the same would be true at the $3$-categorical level?

Comment: @MikeShulman Much appreciated, it looks like this might be the higher existing notion that trivializes the above example. I notice a lack of a 'definition' section -- has "someone" (wink) written it down and not latexed it up (completely understandable as the above took some time and is presumably much shorter), or is the notion still too nebulous for a precise definition? All the examples on the page are just $2$-categories internal to $1$-categories, but the references look more promising.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Interesting, so this would be an example of a naturally occurring $2$-category internalized at the $1$-categorical level -- in light of Kevin's comment above this type of internalization is perhaps all we should expect to occur naturally.

Comment: The nLab page is fairly nebulous, but once you fix particular meanings of "n-category" and "k-category" you can make the definition precise.  See the references linked there: Batanin gave one precise notion of $(n\times 1)$-category, and Douglas-Henriques study, IIRC, 2x1-categories (closely related to the definition you wrote down) and perhaps also mention 1x2-categories.

Answer (score 4):

Bicategories internal to 2-categories with pullbacks are defined in §3 of Douglas–Henriques's [Internal bicategories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.4284). They have two motivating examples described in §1: a bicategory $\mathrm{Bord}_0^2$ of bordisms internal to the 2-category $\mathrm{CAT}$; and a bicategory of conformal nets internal to the 2-category $\mathrm{SYMMONCAT}$.